# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator Ladder operator propertie

Tags: operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

My problem is: I have to prove the next "property" of the quantum harmonic oscillator number operator:

Given

$\hat{N} = a^\dagger a$

Prove:

$\hat{N} | n \rangle = n | n \rangle$

My attempt:
I already show this two properties:

$a^\dagger  | n \rangle = \sqrt{n+1} | n+1 \rangle$

$a  | n \rangle = \sqrt{n} | n-1 \rangle$

So, i think that i can "join" this two in order to have the one that i want, is that correct? I mean, it is possible? Or i have to try it in another way.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you've defined $\mid n \rangle$ by $\mid n \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} (a^{\dagger})^n \mid0\rangle $, then yes this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the operators in the sequence they appear:
\begin{align*}
\hat{N} | n \rangle &= a^\dagger a | n \rangle\\
&= a^\dagger \sqrt{n} | n-1 \rangle\\
&= \sqrt{n} a^\dagger | n-1 \rangle\\
&= \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} | n \rangle\\
&= n | n \rangle
\end{align*}